# SSIS Load Issues with Audit Table

Tags: ssis, load

I am just creating a simple SSIS incremental load to get my head around the process and I'm currently having an issue with my Audit table. What is happening is that the load will run fine and a new row in the audit table will be inserted from the first execution task but when I go to update the AuditEndDate field in the Audit table at the end of the load process, it only updates the first row in the table. Please see down for reference.

My audit table consists of;
AuditID INT (Primary Key)
TaskID INT
AuditStartDate DATETIME
AuditEndDate DATETIME

My loading process is successful and works. I have now introduced an SQL Execution task at the beginning  of the load with a stored procedure that inserts a new row into the audit table that has a new AuditID number and the start date. At the end of the load process I have another SQL execution task that just updates the AuditEndDate field on the same row with a GETDATE().

I am using OLE DB sources

My Load flow looks like this;

[image]

My Stored procedure for Inserting into the audit table in the first task;

```
(
        @TaskID INT 
        , @LoadStartDateTime datetime 
        , @LoadEndDateTime datetime 

)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SET @LoadStartDateTime = ISNULL(@LoadStartDateTime, GETDATE())


    -- Insert the log record
    INSERT INTO [SM_SSIS_Audit_Log]
    (
        TaskID 
        , LoadStartDateTime 
        , LoadEndDateTime 


    ) VALUES (
        @TaskID 
        , @LoadStartDateTime 
        , @LoadEndDateTime 

    )

END
```

My stored procedure for updating the table at the last execution task;

```
(
    @AuditID        INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE SM_SSIS_Audit_Log 
    SET
         LoadEndDateTime  = GETDATE()

    WHERE
        AuditID  = @AuditID

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

My Execution task for inserting is;

```
[SM_SSIS_LoadBegin] ?, NULL, NULL
```

My Execution task for updating is;

```
[SM_SSIS_TaskEnd] @AuditID = ?
```

My Parameter setting in the first execution task is;

[image]

My Parameter settings in the final execution task is;

[image]

My Audit table looks like;

[image]

As you can see it is only updating the first row and not the current row that has been created. Does anyone know what I have done wrong and suggest something please.

If you need more information please comment and I will assist.

Thank you very much!
SM

Comment: Make sure you use the correct parameter marker in your queries (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-query-parameters-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014). Could you show the contents of the first task as well, the one with the insert phase?

Comment: @Gigga, I am using OLE DB sources which say I need to use ?, not sure whether I need to use the @ symbol. I have edited the post to show the information you were after.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the additional info.

First you insert a new row with TaskId plus the dates, then you try to update the row with AuditId as the key? The way it behaves now is because they are different values. As you can see, the insert adds a new row with 0 as the TaskId. Then you update a row, where AuditId is 0.

It seems that AuditId is an identity column, which populates itself. If you'd like to update the latest AuditId, you should output it's value in the [SM_SSIS_LoadBegin]-procedure by using @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() (more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Save this value to a **local variable** in SSIS (not to package parameter you have used, local variables are prefixed as User::nnn), as explained here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114831.

Then at the update task, change the package parameter reference to the local variable you created and it should work.

Comment: Hi thank you for the respnse, managed to figure out this was the problem earlier today so it's all good now! Turns out I needed to define auditID in the stored procedure with AuditID INT = NULL OUTPUT and set it as SET AuditID SCOPE_IDENTITY(). You're right as well as I had used a parameter and not a variable so and I also needed to set the parameter name as the order in the statement and have the inital variable parameter as an OUTPUT not an INPUT . Thanks for the help I appreciate it!